# how to de-host a laravel app from google cloud platform?

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, heidisql

I cannot access my heidisql database because my google cloud trial version is over so I want to de-host my laravel app from google cloud platform and want to develop only on localhost.

Comment: Might be better off contacting GCP support to have your data erased if they don't already do so automatically after some time...

Answer (score 0):

When a free trial ends, you have 30 days to restore your resources by upgrading to a paid account; otherwise, the data and resources are not longer available anymore. You can take a look on the **End of the free trial** section of the [Billing FAQs](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions) to know more about this matter.

**What happens when my free trial ends?**

> After your trial ends, the resources you created during the trial are stopped, but can 
>   be restored if you upgrade to a paid account within 30 days.
>
> Within that 30-day period, you can also contact Google Billing Support
>   to export any data you stored in Google GCP services (other than on
>   Compute Engine). After 30 days, your data and resources are not
>   available, even if you upgrade.
>
> Caution: Because there is no automated way to export data from Compute
>   Engine, you are responsible for exporting any data stored on Compute
>   Engine before your free trial ends.